# How to slice arrays using variables and iterate?

Tags: python

I am trying to store `Val = [32, 43, 26, 50, 20, 27]` and `wt = [16, 12, 4, 8, 3, 9]`, how do I do this through iterating and slicing via variables?

```
res = [4, 2, 77, 7, 66, 6, 2, 5, 5, 6, 32, 16, 43, 12, 26, 4, 50, 8, 20, 3, 27, 9]
```

Before the below

```
len(val) = 3, len(wt) = 3  F = 1 
val = [77, 66]
wt = [7, 6]



elif(tCount > 0):
    N = res[len(val)+len(wt)+F*2+1]
    print("N equals" +str(N))



    val = res[N * 2:2]
    wt = res[3:3 + N * 2:2]
    print(val)
    print(wt)
    print(F)
    print(W)
```

How do I store N to = 6? Then slice the array for val and wt for the next section.

EDIT - My aim is to store N = 6 then, store val with 6 values [32, 43, 26, 50, 20, and 27] wt with [16, 12, 4, 8, 3 and 9] and then I will be passing these into the following function solve(val, W, wt, N, F)

Comment: Can you explain *what* you aim to do, not *how* you aim to do it. What is the input, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: with what logic are you getting val and wt

Comment: For the first loop, I am slicing to get the every second item after N for val and wt is the item after that. However, I don't know how to get that for the set.